# How to detect dimensions of file using File API and Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Using Dropzone.js, I need to detect the dimesions of the image when added files and apply them to its parent `.details` div. The following code code works and return an alert with the added image width.

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file, xhr) {
  var fr;
  fr = new FileReader;
  fr.onload = function() {
    var img;
    img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() {
      return alert(img.width);
    };
    return img.src = fr.result;
  };
  return fr.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

The thing is that I have no idea how to assign the width to its parent `.details` element which set the preview width of the preview.

I try replacing the alert for this code but it doesn't do anything.

```
$(this).parent('.details').css('height',img.height);
```

I'm a bit lost in how to relate the value inside the onload function to applying it to its parent class.

Answer (score 5):

With the latest version of dropzone you don't have to write this code yourself.

Simply read the `file.width` and `file.height` properties that are set on the `file` object when the thumbnail is generated.

The problem, why your CSS doesn't affect the element, is because you didn't specify the unit, `px` in this case. So your code can be:

```
myDropzone.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
  $(this.element).parent('.details').css('height', file.height + 'px');
});
```

Comment: @nikans care to elaborate?

Comment: One does not simply read `file.width` & `file.height` when working with loaded file. You need to use `FileReader()` and do some weird stuff.

Comment: That's how I managed to accept files only larger than 1024x768 (I've been using it for steganography so I just needed about 786432 pixels to cipher data into the image..) 
`accept: function(file, done) {
  var pixels = 0;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(file) { 
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = file.target.result;
    image.onload = function() {
      pixels = this.width * this.height;
      if (pixels < 786432) {
        done("blah");
      }
      else { done(); }
    };
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
`

Comment: @nikans : As I said in my answer: `file.width` and `file.height` are set by dropzone, when the thumbnail is generated. Dropzone does the work for you. I clarified my answer a bit.

Comment: not when I (and possibly the author of the question) needed it to. dropzone doesn't provide a way to get file dimensions on `accept` and possibly `addedfile`

Comment: @nikans - The dimensions are not calculated while `addedFile`, and `accept` are fired. They are calculated before `thumbnail`, `progress` and `success` are fired though.