# how do I get the width and height values from this object in javascript

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone and cropper to upload a file.  I can't figure out how to reference the chosen images width and height.

This is the relevant code:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: '{{ route('user.upload') }}',
    transformFile: function(file, done) {

        console.log(file);
        //console.log(file[height]);

        for (var property in file) {
            output = property + ': ' + file[property]+'; ';
            console.log(output);
        }
```

The console.log(file) line outputs this:

[image]

So it has the height and width.

The looping through the properties of file output this:

[image]

Anyone know how to access height and width here?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @kmoser this is the code that is working now.

```
transformFile: function(file, done) {

    console.log(file['height']);

    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.onload = (function(file) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = file.target.result;
        image.onload = function() { 
            height = this.height;
            width = this.width;
            console.log('1 '+width);
            console.log('1 '+height);
        }; 
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    console.log('2 '+width);
    console.log('2 '+height);
    if (width > height)
    {
        console.log('wider');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('tall');
    }
```

The only issue is that the console.log('2 '+width); outputs before the console.log('1 '+width);

Can I make it wait?

**EDIT 2**

Figured this out as well.

```
async function readFileAsDataURL(file) {
    let result_base64 = await new Promise((resolve) => {

        let reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.onload = (function(file) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = file.target.result;
            image.onload = function(file) { 
                height = this.height;
                width = this.width;
                console.log('1 '+width);
                console.log('1 '+height);
                resolve(reader.result);
            }; 
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    });
    return result_base64;
}

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: '{{ route('user.upload') }}',
    transformFile: async function(file, done) {

        let result = await readFileAsDataURL(file);

        console.log('2 '+width);
        console.log('2 '+height);
        if (width > height)
        {
            console.log('wider');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('tall');
        }
```

Works great!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011164/how-to-detect-dimensions-of-file-using-file-api-and-dropzone-js

Comment: Yes it worked!  Thanks I edited my question as I have a new timing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final Solution

```
async function readFileAsDataURL(file) {
    let result_base64 = await new Promise((resolve) => {

        let reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.onload = (function(file) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = file.target.result;
            image.onload = function(file) { 
                height = this.height;
                width = this.width;
                console.log('1 '+width);
                console.log('1 '+height);
                resolve(reader.result);
            }; 
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    });
    return result_base64;
}

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: '{{ route('user.upload') }}',
    transformFile: async function(file, done) {

        let result = await readFileAsDataURL(file);

        console.log('2 '+width);
        console.log('2 '+height);
        if (width > height)
        {
            console.log('wider');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('tall');
        }
```

Comment: Where do you call `transformFile()` from?

Answer (score -1):

To call the attributes use dot

```
console.log(file.height);
```

Comment: console.log(file["height"]);   ?

Comment: Its not wokring

Answer (score -1):

To access Height and Width, you can use either of them.

```
console.log(file['height']);
```

OR

```
console.log(file.height);
```

Both will give same result.
Dot is used when you are sure of some value present in the attribute, while other way you can use when you are not sure whether it will be undefined or some value will be there

Comment: Are you sure the file which you are consoling is JSON, probably before accessing it using dot you can try doing  .parse() to convert it to JSON

Comment: file.parse() gave me this error: Uncaught TypeError: file.parse is not a function

Comment: I am commenting here because I dont have much reputation, to answer you question: The only issue is that the console.log('2 '+width); outputs before the console.log('1 '+width); You can do async await to wait till it console and proceed, You are facing this because of asynchronous nature of Js

Comment: thanks.  Any idea how to do that?  I can't work it out.

Comment: I see you figured what I meant from async await. Great!